# APA citation not coming up consistently

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style, apa7

I have an overleaf project created using this [template](https://github.com/GarenSidonius/ASU-Dissertation-Template) that is over 200 page long. APA citation in the text are not appearing for some bibitems. Below is the MWE code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,             % Use US letter-size paper
               oneside,                 % No verso and recto differences
               12pt]                    % Use a specific font size
               {memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
              isbn=false,
              dashed=false,
              style=apa]%              
              {biblatex}        
\bibliography{src/sample/library}
\begin{document}
Students can learn and absorb knowledge in a variety of ways depending on their learning styles, and the teacher can present their content in various teaching styles \parencite{felder1988learning}.
The model predicted by the BN is compared with Felder’s scale obtained using the Index of Learning Styles questionnaire \parencite{soloman2005index}
\end{document}
```

For the `felder1988learning` it is appearing as "(R. M. Felder & Silverman, 1988)", while for `soloman2005index` it is appearing as "(Soloman & Felder, 2005)". Below is the entries in bib file corresponding to the two. Why are the citations not consistent, despite having similar format of author names for the two entries? How do I drop the "R. M." from (R. M. Felder & Silverman, 1988)?

```
@article{felder1988learning,
    title        = {Learning and teaching styles in engineering education},
    author       = {Felder, Richard M and Silverman, Linda K},
    year         = 1988,
    journal      = {Engineering education},
    publisher    = {North Carolina},
    volume       = 78,
    number       = 7,
    pages        = {674--681}
}
@article{soloman2005index,
    title        = {Index of learning styles questionnaire},
    author       = {Soloman, Barbara A and Felder, Richard M},
    year         = 2005,
    journal      = {NC State University. Available online at: https://www.engr.ncsu.edu/stem-resources/legacy-site/learning-styles/ (last visited on 02.14.2021)},
    volume       = 70
}
```

Comment: From the entries you have shared so far I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. From https://gist.github.com/moewew/39804b7f8cfb9cb0ea8877f5bb3ae117 I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zM5m.png as expected. The beheaviour you describe would be correct APA style if you cite another paper where a different Felder is the first author (or maybe the same Felder, but in a slightly different format, e.g. `Felder, Richard M` vs `Felder, Richard`).

Comment: Reference for my last claim in the comment above: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/citing-authors-same-surname. If you want us to investigate this issue in your setting further, please consider posting a fully compilable, yet minimal example document that reproduces the behaviour you are seeing with as little code as possible (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Make sure the example you post actually reproduces the issue - some things are context dependent.

Comment: Off-topic: the entry type `@article` would not appear to be the correct choice for the `soloman2005index` entry. Something like `@misc` or `@online` would be far more appropriate.

Comment: @Mico, `soloman2005index` is working as expected, so I'd rather not touch it :P

Comment: @moewe, Thanks for your input. "Felder, Richard M" and "Felder, Richard" were both present, so I fixed the latter to say the same name. It fixed the issue, much thanks to you! Please post that as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the entries you have shared so far I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. With

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{felder1988learning,
    title        = {Learning and teaching styles in engineering education},
    author       = {Felder, Richard M and Silverman, Linda K},
    year         = 1988,
    journal      = {Engineering education},
    publisher    = {North Carolina},
    volume       = 78,
    number       = 7,
    pages        = {674--681}
}
@online{soloman2005index,
    title        = {Index of learning styles questionnaire},
    author       = {Soloman, Barbara A and Felder, Richard M},
    year         = 2005,
    organization = {NC State University},
    url          = {https://www.engr.ncsu.edu/stem-resources/legacy-site/learning-styles/},
    urldate      = {2021-02-14},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{felder1988learning}

ipsum \autocite{soloman2005index}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Felder & Silverman, 1988) ipsum (Soloman & Felder, 2005)]

as expected.

The behaviour you describe would be correct APA style if you cite another paper where a different Felder is the first author (see https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/citing-authors-same-surname).

But it is also possible that both Felders are the same person, they are given in different versions in the `.bib` file, e.g. `Felder, Richard M` vs `Felder, Richard`. In that case it may help to normalise the name to the same version.